# how to get top terms based on tf-idf Python

Tags: python, tf-idf

Here is my python code.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(token_dict.values())
print tfidf_matrix
```

The results show like this:

```
        (0, 210)    0.14152686101
        (0, 1)      0.0707634305049
        (0, 261)    0.212290291515
        (0, 11)     0.135603306032
              : :
        (3, 49)     0.0709465134358
        (3, 37)     0.315905243912
        (3, 374)    0.11487463415
        (3, 192)    0.057437317075
```

What I want to return is top 10(based on their tf*idf) terms' name and tf*idf score per document.

Answer (score 2):

In your tfidf_matrix each row corresponds to a document.  You can take out each row and argsort() it, which gives you the the column of the term with the highest(lowest) value.  This way you can extract it.  Then you can just input the same index to the row in the matrix itself to get the score as well.

```
#convert your matrix to an array to loop over it
mat_array = tfidf_matrix.toarray()

# get your feature names
fn = tfidf.get_feature_names()

for l in mat_array: 
print [(fn[x],l[x]) for x in (l*-1).argsort()][:10]
```

No idea how you would like to output this, but you could obviously do that in a number of ways, or keep everything in a data structure as you loop through and do the outputting afterwards.  The multiplication with -1 is just to get argsort() to rank from high to low for more readable slicing syntax.

Comment: print [(fn[x],l[x]) for x in (l*-1).argsort()][:10]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax